# How to write a vimscript to replace the word under cursor in i mode?

Tags: vimscript

I'm writting a complete script, and when the function is triggered in i mode, I need to delete the word under the cursor and call the function `complete` to put new words. I only know to delete the origin word by `<backspace>`. Is there a good way to delete the word in i mode?

Comment: `:norm! diw` should be enough. And what do you mean the function will be triggered in i mode?

Comment: But using `:normal! diw` and then call `complete`, the position where I put the new word will be different if the cursor is at the end of line or not

Comment: I don't have any experience with utilizing `:h complete()`, sorry. But I don't think some corner cases would be hard to solve. Maybe if you have some test examples, it would be easier to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`complete({startcol}, {matches})` provides the function to replace the old word. You can use `complete(col(".") - ${length}, {matches})` to replace the old word, `${length}` is the length of your old word.

Comment: But in this way you can't delete the part of the word which is on the right side of the cursor.

Comment: You can use `cursor()` to move your cursor to the end of the word. You can learn how to use the function with `:h cursor`

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use c-w in i mode to delete until start of current word, it's much more convenient to switch to normal mode to change the entire word.

```
inoremap <leader>c <c-o>diw<c-r>=complete()<cr>
```

Comment: Of course, <c-x> is a very important sub-mode in vim. So, not very wise to shadow it. You should mention that.

Comment: you don't need to switch to normal mode, you can use `c-o` to switch temporarily to normal mode just for `ciw`, `c-r` also works in insert mode.

Comment: Good points. I found that i need another l operation to move the cursor after switch back to normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

If `complete` conforms to the spec of `'completefunc'` (or can be made to, either by editing or wrapping it):

```
set completefunc=complete
```

Then just use `<C-x>u` in insert mode (see `:help ins-completion`).